# Tag group for multiple sites in kentico?

Tags: tags, kentico

I wanted to know how I can use a tag group for multiple site in Kentico 10 ? Is it possible or there are workarounds ?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can not have the same tag group for 2 or more sites. There is no "global" tag group. Table CMS_TagGroup has the information about all the groups for all sites, and Kentico module is called Taxonomy.  You have to experiment here, there is a field called TagGroupIsAdHoc  by default is always false. You may try to set to  true (i.e. it means a group is shared), but in this case you need to `useal module -> make a change  -> seal the module.`
Here is the condition that you need to change:[image]

These are just some ideas, you need to dig deeper... Essentially what you looking for is custom functionality and not available out the box. Changing system modules is not recommended (might complicate the future upgrades), so you do it at your own risk